# else statement trouble with nested tuples

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on this problem for a few days now and need help understanding why my else statement won't work. The task is to build a lexer, that returns a word and it's type based on a tuple containing all acceptable words and their types. If the word is not in the tuple, it's supposed to return the word with the type 'error'.

I've already tried using any() to scan all pairs in my tuple, if it returns false, then my else statement is meant to kick in. If it return true, it's supposed to 'pass' and continue on with the for loop.

I've looked into using enumerate, and list comprehensions - but I am still a beginner and can't wrap my head around how either would work with the int() check.

```
adv_input = [('direction', 'north'),
             ('verb', 'go'),
             ('verb', 'kill'),
             ('stop', 'the'),
             ('number', 91234)]

def convert_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def scan(input):
    r = []
    stuff = input.split()
    for word in stuff:
        for pair in adv_input:
            if word in pair:
                r.append((pair[0], word))
            elif convert_number(word) in pair:
                r.append((pair[0], convert_number(word)))
            elif any(word in pair for pair in adv_input):
                pass
            else:
                r.append(('error', word))

    return(r)


scan("north go kill 91234 hello")
```

my actual results:

```
[('direction', 'north'), ('verb', 'go'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('error', '91234'), ('error', '91234'), ('error', '91234'), ('error', '91234'), ('number', 91234), ('error', 'hello'), ('error', 'hello'), ('error', 'hello'), ('error', 'hello'), ('error', 'hello')]
```

expected results:

```
[('direction', 'north'), ('verb', 'go'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('number', 91234), ('error', 'hello']
```

Clearly, it's looping too many times through numbers and errors, but I can't figure out why. Please help.

Comment: You can always return `list(set(r))` to avoid duplicates!

Comment: It's because you are checking every pair and appending to the list every time, so it has to iterate through your `adv_input` and append several errors before it gets to the correct match.

Comment: You could put the `else` statement outside that inner loop if a pair is not appended.

Comment: You just need to `break` out of the inner for loop whenever your condition is reached, check my answer below @python_student303

Comment: Thank you @| Funball. If I move the else statement out, does that prevent the unnecessary iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `break` out of the inner for loop whenever a condition matches. Check out the 4 `break` statements I have in the code below

```
adv_input = [('direction', 'north'),
             ('verb', 'go'),
             ('verb', 'kill'),
             ('stop', 'the'),
             ('number', 91234)]

def convert_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def scan(input):
    r = []
    stuff = input.split()
    for word in stuff:
        for pair in adv_input:
            if word in pair:
                r.append((pair[0], word))
                break
            elif convert_number(word) in pair:
                r.append((pair[0], convert_number(word)))
                break
            elif any(word in pair for pair in adv_input):
                pass
            else:
                r.append(('error', word))
                break

    return(r)

print(scan("north go kill 91234 hello"))
```

The output now becomes

```
[('direction', 'north'), ('verb', 'go'), 
('verb', 'kill'), ('error', '91234'), ('error', 'hello')]
```

Comment: Thank you Devesh! This worked liked a charm. Why is 'break' needed? I thought if the branch in the if statement was true, it would execute any code under that branch and then stop. What am I missing?

Comment: No it won’t stop, your inner for loop of for pair in adv_loop will run for every pair for a word, leading to the repetitive results of same type as you saw, in general any for or while only stops executing when you break put of it, or we reach the stop condition.

Comment: Also if the answer helped you, it would be great if you could accept it :)